# iOS Swift Realm asyncOpen not working without internet

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: realmURL))

Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { realm, error in
  if let realm = realm {

    // Realm successfully opened, with all remote data available
  }
else if let error = error {
    // Handle error that occurred while opening or downloading the contents of the Realm
  }
}
```

I used the above code to get Asynchronously Opening Realm, but its not working without internet.

Answer (score 0):

As per realm [Documents](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

> In addition, synchronized Realms wait for all remote content available
>   at the time the operation began to be downloaded and available
>   locally.

`syncConfiguration:` will wait for all remote content available

**For Example:**

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: realmURL))
Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { realm, error in
  if let realm = realm {
    // Realm successfully opened, with all remote data available
  } else if let error = error {
    // Handle error that occurred while opening or downloading the contents of the Realm
  }
}
```